# how to use JwtAuthProvider in ServiceStack?

Tags: servicestack, jwt

Could you please explain how to use JwtAuthProvider in ServiceStack authentication and consume the service in .net client?

Answer (score 2):

The docs on the JWT AuthProvider includes both server registration and several c# client examples for authenticating with JWT: http://docs.servicestack.net/jwt-authprovider

If you still have questions after reading the docs, ask a new more specific question on exactly what you’re still having difficulty with.

Comment: I tried that but it is very complicated. I got the bearer token but this line always returns null, do you have any idea why it is null? **var jwtProvider = (JwtAuthProvider)AuthenticateService.GetAuthProvider(JwtAuthProvider.Name)** here, jwtProvider is NULL,

Comment: @tika Do you have a `JwtAuthProvider` registered in your `AuthFeature` Plugin? (first code sample in [/jwt-authprovider](http://docs.servicestack.net/jwt-authprovider)). If so how many AuthProviders does `AuthenticateService.GetAuthProviders()` return and is one of them a `JwtAuthProvider`?